# Как сделать извилистую дорогу

Tags: c#, unity3d

Как сделать извилистую дорогу как в этой игре
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Нарисовать дорогу на карте и использовать готовую или автогенерировать случайные повороты на прямой определённой длины?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Конкретно в даной игре автоматически генерируется дорога (случайные повороты).

Скорее всего на основе кривых Безье/сплайнов, вокруг которых генерируются Mash-ы обьектов уровня. Нужно копать в эту сторону.

Comment: А для поворотов заранее заготовленны префабы?

Comment: Неа, генерировать кривые безье во время игры. Просто подобрать правильно параметры генерации которые бы тебе подходили бы.

Comment: а как генерируется сам объект это же не примитивы, кривые Безье сгенерированны теперь же нужно как-то сделать чтобы там появился объект.

Comment: Можно например использовать чужой ассет: https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/modeling/splinemesh-104989 а можно написать свой. А создание своего -- это слишком общий вопрос даже для отдельного вопроса на SO, что уже говорить про вопрос в коментарии.

Comment: вот еще тутор по работе со сплайнами и по генерации обьектов по них и вокруг них: https://catlikecoding.com/unity/tutorials/curves-and-splines/

Comment: а можете дать пример как по кривой Безье сгенерировать mesh?

Comment: Последняя ссылка, которую я кидал, уже с таким примером. Ты вообще смотрел что я тебе кидал? Смотри внимательнее пример кода SplineDecorator

Comment: как сделать чтобы объект двигался по этой дороге с помощью Rigidbody (неохото создавать новый топик)

Comment: может тогда изменишь вопрос на "Чатик помощи Aimon Z.?" Почитай правила ресурса. Там на знаке вопроса  справа сверху кликаешь, а потом кликаешь на надпис "справка". В частности присмотрись к этой ветке справки: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask